# How to populate a Custom List Adapter with more than 2 values ?- JAVA android

Tags: java, android, object, populate, custom-adapter

I'm trying to populate a Custom Adapter with a Multiple Values Objects Array but something is going wrong. I commented on the custom adapter code below where is my error.

This is my **Scorecard** Activity Code:

```
ObjectItem[] holeData = new ObjectItem[20];

for (int i = 1; i <= hole_counter; i++) {
            // Getting values from Shared Prefs
            strokeArray[i] = mySharedData.getInt("hole_" + i + "_stroke", 0);
            parArray[i] = mySharedData.getInt("hole_" + i + "_par", 0);
            // Populating Objects Array
            holeData[i] = new ObjectItem(i, strokeArray[i], parArray[i]);
        }

HoleListAdapter adapter = new HoleListAdapter(getListView().getContext(), holeData);
setListAdapter(adapter);

/** Object Items Class */
public class ObjectItem {
    public int hole;
    public int strokes;
    public int par;

    // constructor
    public ObjectItem(int hole, int strokes, int par) {
        this.hole = hole;
        this.strokes = strokes;
        this.par = par;
    }
}
```

This is my custom adapter **HoleListAdapter** Code:

```
public class HoleListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Scorecard.ObjectItem> {

protected Context mContext;
Scorecard.ObjectItem mHoleData[] = null;

public HoleListAdapter(Context context, Scorecard.ObjectItem[] holeData) {
    super(context, R.layout.scorecard_list_item, holeData);

    mContext = context;
    mHoleData = holeData;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.scorecard_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iconImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pin_icon);
        holder.holeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hole_number_title);
        holder.strokeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stroke_number_title);
        holder.parTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.par_number_title);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Scorecard.ObjectItem objectItem = mHoleData[position + 1];

    holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pin);
    // HAVING ERROS ON THESE LINES BELOW
    holder.holeTextView.setText(objectItem.hole);
    holder.strokeTextView.setText(objectItem.strokes);
    holder.parTextView.setText(objectItem.par);

    return convertView;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView iconImageView;
    TextView holeTextView;
    TextView strokeTextView;
    TextView parTextView;
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Process: com.gca.plusgolf, PID: 17808
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
        // The line below is the Error's Place that I mentioned in the HoleListAdapter Code
        at com.gca.plusgolf.HoleListAdapter.getView(HoleListAdapter.java:54)
```

If is there a better way to populate a custom adapter with 3 values please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: post the stack trace.

Comment: @AmitGupta there is the trace. tks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `setTag()` at the `convertView == null` branch:

```
if (convertView == null)
{
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.scorecard_list_item, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.iconImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pin_icon);
    holder.holeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hole_number_title);
    holder.strokeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stroke_number_title);
    holder.parTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.par_number_title);
    //forgot to do that
    convertView.setTag(holder)
} ...
```

That is why when later you are trying to get tag, you get nothing.

Comment: I tried and I keep having the same problem. Do you think that is the way that Im trying to retrieve these values ? with objectItem in the custom adapter HoleListAdapter Code ?

Comment: @PedroGCA have you checked values of `mHoleData` with debugger?

Comment: mHoleData = [Lcom.example.app.Scorecard$ObjectItem;@433de628

Comment: @PedroGCA it's just the address. Please try to add the string I mentioned and post new logcat with updated code

Comment: I've just included the string and debugged. My **setImageResource** and **holder** seems to be ok.

However the problem seems to be one line below with the **objectItem** that is **null**.

here is the trace:

`objectItem = null`
`objectItem.strokes = java.lang.NullPointerException`
`objectItem.hole = java.lang.NullPointerException`
`objectItem.par = java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: OK, I've just changed the line in **(HoleListAdapter)**
from
`Scorecard.ObjectItem objectItem = mHoleData[position];`
to
`Scorecard.ObjectItem objectItem = mHoleData[position + 1];`

Because my for loop starts with 1 as you can see in **Scorecard Activity**.

When I debug now I have the values for `objectItem`, `objectItem.strokes`, `objectItem.par`, `objectItem.hole` instead of `NullPointerException` but the app still breaking in the same line. This is my stack trace now `Process: com.example.app, PID: 17808
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1`

Comment: @PedroGCA what's on the line 54? BTW, array should start with 0, that is why you should replace `int i = 1` with `int i = 0` in `for` loop and also `position+1` to `position`